# How do I correctly load the char array of a grayscale BMP using CImage?

Tags: c++, c, image, visual-c++, bmp

I have the following code:

```
cout<<"Please enter the name of your BMP image file: "<<endl;
cin>>fname;
nP = fname.c_str(); 
CImage input = CImage();
input.Load(nP);

// allocate space for host source image
unsigned char *pHI, *pCI;
width = input.GetWidth();
height = input.GetHeight();
pCI = (unsigned char *)input.GetBits();
pHI = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * width * height);

// fill array with CImage array content
srand (time(NULL));
for (int cnt = 0; cnt < sizeof(unsigned char) * width * height; cnt++){
    pHI[cnt] = pCI[cnt];
}
```

But the program gives me an error when I try to get the width and height.

"Debug Assertion Failed! ... Expression: m_hBitmap !=0"

If you have any ideas as to what could be causing this / what I should change, I'd appreciate the help!

: )

Comment: The image file is not in the directory you expect?

Comment: The image is in the same directory as the program, and there are no problems loading the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to check is that `input.Load()` is successful.  It returns an `HRESULT` and you should check the value of this.  It's going to be a clue as to what's going on.

[Link to CImage::Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf4bytf8.aspx)

You can interpret what an HRESULT means here:

[Details on HRESULT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb401631.aspx)

Good luck, but more information is needed.

After edit:  Further more, you can only use CImage::Load() for DIB sections. See this link for more info:  [CImage class reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwea7by5.aspx)